# How to read data from serial port SICK LMS200?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port, package, lidar

I would like to read data from SICK LMS200 Lidar scanner through serial port. I can see the serial port as /dev/ttyUSB0. I just do not know how to get data out of it.

I've tried to install [The Sick LIDAR Matlab/C++ Toolbox](http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/) under Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS using the manual installation as shown in toolbox manual.

I untar the file:

```
$tar -xzvf sicktoolbox-1.0.1.tar.gz
```

That's what I get after running ./configure (not sure if it's helpfull)

```
me@MyPC:~/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1$ ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for g77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for f77... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking for g95... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for ftn... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking for gnuplot... no
configure: WARNING: *** gnuplot not found, some examples will not be built.
checking for doxygen... no
configure: WARNING: doxygen not found - will not generate any doxygen documentation
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking linux/serial.h usability... yes
checking linux/serial.h presence... yes
checking for linux/serial.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for int16_t... yes
checking for uint16_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint8_t... yes
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... (cached) yes
checking types of arguments for select... int,fd_set *,struct timeval *
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating c++/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/ld_config/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/ld_config/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/ld_more_config/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/ld_more_config/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/ld_multi_sector/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/ld_multi_sector/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/ld_single_sector/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/ld/ld_single_sector/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_config/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_config/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_mean_values/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_mean_values/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_partial_scan/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_partial_scan/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_plot_values/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_plot_values/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_real_time_indices/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_real_time_indices/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_set_variant/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_set_variant/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_simple_app/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_simple_app/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_stream_range_and_reflect/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_stream_range_and_reflect/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_subrange/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/examples/lms/lms_subrange/src/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/drivers/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/drivers/ld/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/drivers/ld/sickld-1.0/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/drivers/lms/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/drivers/lms/sicklms-1.0/Makefile
config.status: creating c++/drivers/base/src/SickConfig.hh
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

After running `$make` I get this error:

```
me@ MyPC:~/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1$ make
Making all in c++
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++'
Making all in drivers
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/me/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers'
Making all in ld
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/me/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers/ld'
Making all in sickld-1.0
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/me/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers/ld/sickld-1.0'
/bin/sh ../../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src  -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src   -g -O2 -MT SickLD.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SickLD.Tpo -c -o SickLD.lo SickLD.cc
mkdir .libs
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -g -O2 -MT SickLD.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SickLD.Tpo -c SickLD.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/SickLD.o
SickLD.cc: In member function 'void SickToolbox::SickLD::_flushTCPRecvBuffer()':
SickLD.cc:4137:35: warning: ignoring return value of 'ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
        read(_sick_fd,&null_byte,1);
                                   ^
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -g -O2 -MT SickLD.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SickLD.Tpo -c SickLD.cc -o SickLD.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/SickLD.Tpo .deps/SickLD.Plo
/bin/sh ../../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src  -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src   -g -O2 -MT SickLDMessage.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SickLDMessage.Tpo -c -o SickLDMessage.lo SickLDMessage.cc
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -g -O2 -MT SickLDMessage.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SickLDMessage.Tpo -c SickLDMessage.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/SickLDMessage.o
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -g -O2 -MT SickLDMessage.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SickLDMessage.Tpo -c SickLDMessage.cc -o SickLDMessage.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/SickLDMessage.Tpo .deps/SickLDMessage.Plo
/bin/sh ../../../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src  -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src   -g -O2 -MT SickLDBufferMonitor.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SickLDBufferMonitor.Tpo -c -o SickLDBufferMonitor.lo SickLDBufferMonitor.cc
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -I../../../../c++/drivers/base/src -g -O2 -MT SickLDBufferMonitor.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/SickLDBufferMonitor.Tpo -c SickLDBufferMonitor.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/SickLDBufferMonitor.o
In file included from SickLDBufferMonitor.hh:24:0,
                 from SickLDBufferMonitor.cc:24:
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh: In member function 'void SickToolbox::SickBufferMonitor<SICK_MONITOR_CLASS, SICK_MSG_CLASS>::_readBytes(uint8_t*, int, unsigned int) const':
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh:356:47: error: there are no arguments to 'getdtablesize' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'getdtablesize' must be available [-fpermissive]
       num_active_files = select(getdtablesize(),&file_desc_set,0,0,(timeout_value > 0) ? &timeout_val : 0);
                                               ^
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh:356:47: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh:370:73: error: there are no arguments to 'read' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'read' must be available [-fpermissive]
      num_bytes_read = read(_sick_fd,&dest_buffer[total_num_bytes_read],1);
                                                                         ^
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh: In static member function 'static void* SickToolbox::SickBufferMonitor<SICK_MONITOR_CLASS, SICK_MSG_CLASS>::_bufferMonitorThread(void*)':
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh:456:18: error: there are no arguments to 'usleep' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'usleep' must be available [-fpermissive]
       usleep(1000);
                  ^
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh: In instantiation of 'void SickToolbox::SickBufferMonitor<SICK_MONITOR_CLASS, SICK_MSG_CLASS>::_readBytes(uint8_t*, int, unsigned int) const [with SICK_MONITOR_CLASS = SickToolbox::SickLDBufferMonitor; SICK_MSG_CLASS = SickToolbox::SickLDMessage; uint8_t = unsigned char]':
SickLDBufferMonitor.cc:59:2:   required from here
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh:356:47: error: 'getdtablesize' was not declared in this scope
       num_active_files = select(getdtablesize(),&file_desc_set,0,0,(timeout_value > 0) ? &timeout_val : 0);
                                               ^
../../../../c++/drivers/base/src/SickBufferMonitor.hh:370:73: error: 'read' was not declared in this scope
      num_bytes_read = read(_sick_fd,&dest_buffer[total_num_bytes_read],1);
                                                                         ^
make[4]: *** [SickLDBufferMonitor.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/me/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers/ld/sickld-1.0'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/me/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers/ld'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++/drivers'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1/c++'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
me@ MyPC:~/smetiste/Sick/sicktoolbox-1.0.1$
```

I've heard that using "old" packages with newer releases may be tricky. But is there any chance to make it work?

Is there any other way how to get data from this scanner on Linux since it doesn't have any internal memory?

Comment: FWIW that package seems to build successfully on a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system., but fails in a similar manner as you saw on a Debian 8 jessie system

Answer (score 1):

The protocol is relatively straightforward and [well documented](http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/docs/sick-lms-telegram-listing.pdf). Don't be daunted by the size of the documentation, for practical use you need a very small subset (commands `10h,20h`and responses `90h,91h,92h,B0h` to start with).

Here's a little Python script that should get you started:

```python
import binascii
import serial
import threading

# =============================================================================

SERIAL_PORT = 'COM6'
# NB: Different crystal, x8 multiplier
SERIAL_BAUDRATE = int(500000 * 14745600 / 16000000 / 8)
SERIAL_TIMEOUT = 1

# =============================================================================

def lms200_crc(data):
  crc16 = 0
  byte = [0,0]
  for c in data:
    byte[1] = byte[0]
    byte[0] = ord(c)

    if (crc16 & 0x8000):
      crc16 = (crc16 & 0x7FFF) << 1
      crc16 ^= 0x8005
    else:
      crc16 = crc16<< 1

    crc16 ^= (byte[1] << 8) | byte[0]

  return crc16

# =============================================================================

class LMS200Telegram(object):
  def __init__(self, data=None):
    if data:
      if len(data) < 7:
        raise RuntimeError("Invalid telegram size")
      if data[0] != '\x02':
        raise RuntimeError("Invalid STX")
      self.address = ord(data[1])
      self.length = ord(data[2]) + (ord(data[3]) * 256)
      self.payload = data[4:-2]
      self.crc = ord(data[-2]) + (ord(data[-1]) * 256)
    else:
      self.address = 0
      self.length = 0
      self.payload = ''
      self.crc = 0

  def generate(self):
    data = '\x02' + chr(self.address)
    self.length = len(self.payload)
    data += chr(self.length & 0xFF)
    data += chr((self.length >> 8) & 0xFF)
    data += self.payload
    self.crc = lms200_crc(data)
    data += chr(self.crc & 0xFF)
    data += chr((self.crc >> 8) & 0xFF)
    return data

class LMS200Command(object):
  def __init__(self, payload):
    if len(payload) < 1:
      raise RuntimeError("Invalid payload size")
    self.opcode = ord(payload[0])
    self.body = payload[1:]

class LMS200Response(object):
  def __init__(self, payload):
    if len(payload) < 2:
      raise RuntimeError("Invalid payload size")
    self.opcode = ord(payload[0])
    self.status = ord(payload[-1])
    self.body = payload[1:-1]

# =============================================================================

def cmd_reset_sensor():
  t = LMS200Telegram()
  t.payload = '\x10'
  return t

def cmd_start_measurement():
  t = LMS200Telegram()
  t.payload = '\x20\x20'
  return t

# =============================================================================

class LMS200Interface(object):
  def __init__(self, port, baudrate, timeout):
    self.port = port
    self.baudrate = baudrate
    self.timeout = timeout
    self.serial = None
    self.serial_rlock = threading.Lock()
    self.serial_wlock = threading.Lock()
    self.buffer = []

  def open_port(self):
    self.serial = serial.Serial(port=self.port
      , baudrate=self.baudrate
      , timeout=self.timeout)

  def close_port(self):
    self.serial.close()
    self.serial = None

  def process_data(self, data):
    self.buffer += data

  def write_telegram(self, t):
    self.serial.flush()
    with self.serial_wlock:
      self.serial.write(t.generate())
    with self.serial_rlock:
      while True:
        ack = self.serial.read(1)
        if len(ack) > 0:
          if ack == '\x06':
            return True
          elif ack == '\x15':
            return False
          else:
            raise RuntimeError("Invalid value received (neither ACK, nor NACK)")

  def worker(self):
    if not self.serial:
      raise RuntimeError("Serial port not initialized.")

    print "Reading serial port '%s'..." % self.port

    while(not self.stop_flag):
      data = self.serial.read(1024)
      if len(data) > 0:
        print "Got %d bytes." % len(data)
        self.process_data(data)

  def run(self):
    lms.open_port()
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
    self.stop_flag = False
    self.thread.start()

  def stop(self):
    self.stop_flag = True
    self.thread.join()
    lms.close_port()

# =============================================================================

lms = LMS200Interface(SERIAL_PORT, SERIAL_BAUDRATE, SERIAL_TIMEOUT)

lms.run()
```

You'd still need to extend the `process_data` method to:

- Detect and separate the individual telegram frames.

  - Simplest way is to find the occurrences of the STX byte. Address byte is often constant, so you can actually search for e.g. `0x02 0x80`. You can also do some validation of the length. Then just try to read the payload, and see if CRCs match.
- When you identify the telegram, you need to parse the payload.

  - Identify payload type by the command/response byte.
  - Interpret the payload using the Python [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module.
- Handle the measured data as you need. The exact form will depend on the measurement mode. For example in the basic measurement mode, you will have an array of 361 16bit distances in mm, taken in 0.5 degree steps. You need to mask out the flags stored in most significant bits, and handle special values that represent error conditions.

I haven't implemented this in the script, since it was written only to do some basic communication tests when we had compatibility issues with our serial cards.

Answer (score 1):

Including unistd.h header files in  SickBufferMonitor.hh & SickLIDAR.hh solves the issue and make ends successfully